# php write text file to windows file server

Tags: php, drupal, file-io

Php is not my strong suit and I am getting an error I don't understand.
I am using PHP 5.2 and drupal 6 is calling a php function with these contents.

I can successfully write a file to the server running this script but not to another Windows (file) server where I need the file to go.

Here is my php code:

```
try{
    $outputFile = "//myserver/dir1/dir2/dir_with_everybody_write_permission/print.txt";
    $fh = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
    $filecontents = "script to be written";
    fwrite($fh, $filecontents);
    fclose($fh);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    form_set_error('', t('File Write Error'));
}
```

My errors:

```
[function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\web\apache\htdocs\sites\all\modules\dirA\X.module on line 161.
warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\web\apache\htdocs\sites\all\modules\dirA\X.module on line 164.
warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\web\apache\htdocs\sites\all\modules\dirA\X.module on line 165.
```

Why is it failing to open the filestream?

thank you for your consideration.

Comment: If you know the answer why did you ask ? Yes it cannot open that file.  Maybe not enough permissions.

Comment: The directory has everybody write permissions and no files in it.

Comment: Does the webserver have permissions to see that server? Can you read a file off it?

Comment: Yes I have logged into the web server and created/read files from the file server

Comment: Does your webserver run as you, or does it have its own username and permissions?

Comment: That is a good questions, I believe I should look at my phpinfo file to find the answer.  I didnt think it would matter if the file server folder has everybody permission.

Comment: It turns out I can create files on my file server on //myserver/dir1/ but if I try to go to //myserver/dir1/dir2/  then I am getting the same error. This folder should have inherited permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No such file or directory

I'd say you're writing to the wrong directory.

Comment: It was a sharing and permissions issue which is about the same as the wrong directory.